# jQuery replace one class with another if ul li class is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a form builder, I would like to change the appearance, for example color of the contents. When the class equal to active should get a white color of the text but when the rest are not active the text should be black instead.

How can I do this with generated 2 class?

Anyway I found something on this forum but it seems not working for me :

```js
 $('.game-star').addClass('game-star2').removeClass('game-star');
```

```css
.game-star  ul li h3 {
 font-size:14px;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:24px;
 float:left;
 font-weight:100;
 margin-top:8px;
}

.game-star2  ul li h3 {
 font-size:14px;
 color:#fff;
 line-height:24px;
 float:left;
 font-weight:100;
 margin-top:8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="game-star" style="height: 198px; overflow: hidden;">
  <ul>
    <li class="Active">
      <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
      <!-- <img src="../images/sideGameMenu1.png"/ class="winner-nameMoolar" "> -->
      <h3 class="winner-name">Major Millions<br>
        RMB 1000.00</h3>
      
      <!-- <p>RMB 625.78</p> --> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
      <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah<br>
        RMB 3,266.41</h3>
      <!-- <p></p> --> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
      <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah Isis<br>
        RMB 4,982.78</h3>
      <!-- <p></p> --> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
      <h3 class="winner-name">发大财<br>
        RMB 8,888.88</h3>
      <!-- <p>RMB 396.42</p> --> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
      <h3 class="winner-name">我发我发我发发发<br>
        RMB 9,999.99</h3>
      <!-- <p>RMB 28.89</p> --> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


my CSS :
```

Comment: Does it have to be two CSS classes? Or can it be something like this... `.game-star ul li[class=Active] h3 { ... }`

Comment: It's working fine to me. Did you check the console, if there's an error?

Comment: Try  jQuery('.game-star').addClass('game-star2').removeClass('game-star');

Comment: @Matt Hi matt , can you provide more details on this particular code? as im news on this thing . Thanks you matt

Comment: @Jows Hi Jows , there is no errror but seems not changing .. i have no clue on this. Kindly advise

Comment: @MorganNg Give me a moment, I'll type it up in the answer.

Comment: You have set color:#fff for both class. You should change in one of them.It might work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your style to:

```
.game-star  ul li,.game-star2  ul li {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    line-height:24px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-top:8px;
}

.game-star ul li.Active,.game-star2  ul li.Active{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandip your code working perfectly without using jQuery , Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using two different CSS classes, you can use one and utilize the [CSS Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). This selector is applied to the CSS selector you want it to be used on, for example `.game-star ul li[class=Active]`. It tell the CSS to look for an element with the name of `game-star` that has a child node of `ul` and a `ul` that has a child node of `li` **WITH** the attribute of `class=Active`. It comes in handy to simplify stuff that had to be done with JavaScript.

So instead of managing and changing class names with JavaScript, you only have to add or remove the attribute `class=Active` on your li. Now, the example I have given you is actually a bad practice example. The good practice would be something like this `.game-star ul li[data-active=Active]` would be more of a correct practice. The reason why is you never want to use a **CLASS ATTRIBUTE IN A ATTRIBUTE SELECTOR** the reason why? It because that already built in this way... `.game-star ul li.Active` You can compound selectors, name, and id together to add more ***emphasis*** on your target. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

So my recommendation would be this for your code:

HTML

```
    <div class="game-star" style="height: 198px; overflow: hidden;">

<ul>
    <li data-active="true">
        <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
        <!-- <img src="../images/sideGameMenu1.png"/ class="winner-nameMoolar" "> -->   
        <h3 class="winner-name">Major Millions<br>RMB 1000.00</h3>

        <!-- <p>RMB 625.78</p> -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="game-star-icon"></div> 
        <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah<br>RMB 3,266.41</h3>
        <!-- <p></p> -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
        <h3 class="winner-name">Major Moolah Isis<br>RMB 4,982.78</h3>
        <!-- <p></p> -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
        <h3 class="winner-name">发大财<br>RMB 8,888.88</h3>
        <!-- <p>RMB 396.42</p> -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="game-star-icon"></div>
        <h3 class="winner-name">我发我发我发发发<br>RMB 9,999.99</h3>
        <!-- <p>RMB 28.89</p> -->
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.game-star ul li[data-active=true] h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:24px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-top:8px;
}
```

EDIT:
If you still wish to do it your way, here in a fiddle for yours. Do remember to change the colors to what you desire! :)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o583tc0q/1/)

Comment: Hi Matt , your code seems not working as it set all the word become white even the class not equal to active

Comment: Okay, well here the fiddle how you were suppose to do it. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ob3ux85/)

Answer (score -2):

I updated the code. The classes is equal. Active is white color of the text and the rest are not active the text should be black instead.

```
.game-star  ul li h3,
.game-star2  ul li h3{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    line-height:24px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-top:8px;
}

.game-star  ul li.active h3,
.game-star2  ul li.active h3 {
    color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pyjuk106/2/

Comment: No, the code runs fine. I just use the fiddle. If you look at the inspect, it **does** change the name of the element, but if you look at the css, it is exactly the same so therefore it only *looks* like nothing is changing.

Here is my fiddle so you can see.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o583tc0q/)

I also updated my fiddle so if they choose this way it would work.

Comment: I updated the code. The classes is equal. Active is white color of the text and the rest are not active the text should be black instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/pyjuk106/2/